# How to get the folds themselves that are partitioned internally in sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm using:

> sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score

to make a cross validation and get the results of each run.

The output of this function is the scores.

Is there a method to get the folds (partitions) themselves that are partitioned internally in the cross_val_score function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to extract the internal cross validation splits used in the `cross_val_score`, as this function does not expose any state about it. As mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html), either a k-fold or stratified k-fold with `k=3` will be used.

However, if you need to keep track of the cross validation splits used, you can explicitly pass in the `cv` argument of `cross_val_score` by creating your own [cross validation iterators](http://scikit-learn.org/0.12/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators):

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.svm import SVC

iris = load_iris()
kf = KFold(len(iris.target), 5, random_state=0)
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=kf)
```

so that it uses the splits you specified exactly instead of rolling its own.

Comment: I want to make sure of something, is there any randomness in splitting the partitions? or the same partitions is generated for the same kfold settings and target labels?

Comment: There is randomness in the splits controlled by the argument ``random_state``. If you do not specify that, ``numpy``'s internal random state will be used and results over multiple runs might be different. For the case of ``KFold``, randomness only applied if ``shuffle=True``.

Comment: in StratifiedKFold there is no parameter called "shuffle" or "random_state", so what's the case?

Comment: At least as of [sklearn version 0.18](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold), it does have those parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The default cross validator for [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) is a StratifiedKFold with K=3 for classification. You can get a cross validation iterator instead, by using the [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold) and looping over the splits as shown in the example.

Comment: yes, I know I can do that but cross_val_score save lots of effort, so I'm looking for a method to extract the folds while using it.